# Prime number beetween 90 and 150

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods, numbers

I wanted to do this exercise that professor gave to our class but I don't know how to do it:

```
Write a method, called first, that returns the most small prime number between 90 and 150.
```

Well that could be quite easy...if I could use loops like `for` or similar but i can't. I can just use if, Array, Method and other really basic things, no libraries.

The only 2 solution that i found is to write around 60 IF or just to write

```
int prime(){
    return 97;
   }
```

Please help me to do it or I have to deliver it in this last way :'D

Comment: There are many, many examples of how to find the next largest prime number on the internet.  Find one of those, **spend time to understand how it works** (or you will not learn, which is the whole reason you are in school), and then run that code starting at 90.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework dump with zero effort.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not english and i really didnt know how to search that in english. I will check in the net again now :) i founded answer only by using FOR or WHILE

Comment: This problem seems to be more about how to do it without using a loop, than about how to find a prime number. This can be done using recursive call.

Comment: @FredK that's a good suggestion; I'm betting that's the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without traditional "loops" by making a recursive function, a function that calls itself. Here's some pseudo code:

```
int nearestPrime(int val) {
    if (val is prime) {
        return val;
    } else {
        return nearestPrime(val + 1);
    }
}
```